# Помогите настроить форму отправки сообщения на php

Tags: php, php7

Не могу настроить форму, пытался всё сделать, в конце добавил вывод текста, но он не сработал из-за чего скорее всего и не работает вся форма, ошибку не могу найти. Буду рад если укажите на ошибки.

```
   <form class="button" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
        <div class="user"></div>
        <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" name="contactname" id="contactname">
        <div class="telephone"></div>
        <input class="name number" type="text" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="number" id="numbers">
        <button name="submit"><p>ПОЛУЧИТЬ РАСЧЁТ</p></button>
  </form>
```

вот php код

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['contactname'])) {$name = $_POST['contactname'];}
if (isset($_POST['number'])) {$email = $_POST['number'];}
print_r($email);
//Если форма отправлена
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//Проверка Поля ИМЯ
  if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'ivan-trushko@ramler.ru'; //email
    $body = "Name: $contactname \n\n Number:\n $number";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
     echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: По умолчанию `button` имеет тип `button`, не `submit`. И вообще надо объяснять что не получается, а не ждать когда придут телепаты и все поймут.

Comment: последняя проверка не получается, т.к. echo не выводит сообщение

Comment: Пора научиться свой код дебагать чтобы понимать что в нем происходит.

Comment: В этом и смысл сообщения, я сам не могу найти ошибку

Comment: Еще раз - начните __дебагать__ код. Просто сообщения выводите в телах ифов чтобы понять срабатывают они у вас или нет. На печать выводите данные - `var_dump`, `print_r`. Всё вам сделали уже, осталось научиться пользоваться.